# Trying to create a username and convert user input to be lower case only, I'm only a student, how am i messing up for str.lower() command?

Tags: python-3.x, lowercase

Username needs to be lower case only and no matter where i add .lower I'm not getting a lowercase value returned or on the csv file I've printed to.

Thanks in advance for any help

```
def main():
    first_name = input("What is your first name? ").lower()
    last_name = input("What is your last name? ").lower()
    password = input("What is your password? ")
    if len(password) < 5:
        print("Password must be at least 5 characters long")
        password = input("What is your password? ")
    username = first_name.[0:3] + last_name.[-2:] + str(random.randint(10, 99))  # generate username using first 3 letters
    # of first name, last 2 letters of last name, and 2 random digits (imported via random)
    print("Your username is: ", username)
    print("Your encrypted password is: ", encrypt(password))
    with open('user.csv', 'w') as user_file:  # open file in write mode
        user_writer = csv.writer(user_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"',
                                 quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)  # create csv writer object
        user_writer.writerow([first_name, last_name, username, encrypt(password)])  # write to csv file


def encrypt(password):
   enc=[[" " for i in range(len(password))] for j in range(5)]  # create 5x5 grid
   flag=0
   row=0 # this is defining the row and whether it travels up or down a row (flag)
   for i in range(len(password)):
       enc[row][i]=password[i]
       if row==0:
           flag=0
       elif row==5-1:
           flag=1
       if flag==0:
            row+=1
       else:
            row-=1 #char index same as column number, only need row number
           # if flag =0 increment row number and if flag = 1 decrement row number
           # if row number of char is 0, flag is 0, if row is 5-1, flag is 1
   ct=[]
   for i in range(5):
       for j in range(len(password)):
           if enc[i][j]!=" ":
               ct.append(enc[i][j]) #reading grid row by row and eliminating spaces
   cipher="".join(ct) #join the list of characters into a string
   return cipher
```

*edited per request

Answer (score 0):

The `lower` method is part of the `str` class, not the *builtin* `input` (`input` returns a `str`). So you want to change your lines that say:

```
first_name = input.lower("What is your first name? ")
```

to

```
first_name = input("What is your first name? ").lower()
```

Also, you don't need the call `lower` ***again*** on the first_name and last_name slices as you do later in your code. Which is also incorrect: it should be `... first_name[0:3].lower() ...` )

Comment: Thank you, the multiple .lowers were me adding it everywhere i could to make it work, will amend and fix. 

I have added the code as you said, I still get a capital when the user inputs a capital in the First/Last name area. :(

`def main():
    first_name = input("What is your first name? ").lower()
    last_name = input("What is your last name? ").lower()
    password = input("What is your password? ")`

Comment: I thought that might have been the case (trying it everywhere). Please edit your question and append your code as it is now, (below your original) as I can see no reason for this not to work from here.

Comment: What version of Python are you running?

Comment: all updated, I'm using Python 3.9 on Pycharm

Comment: Once I've removed the invalid dots before your slices (in your new code above), and omitted the encrypt function calls (by necessity of course), it runs just fine for me. So I suspect you're doing something in your encryption function to change the other variables?

Comment: e.g. I suspect your print("Your username is: ", username) in your code above returns lowercase username, yes?

Comment: no it doesn't this is what I don't understand, everything in my code in my limited understanding should be giving me lower case but it isn't lmao.

I've edited the question and included my encryption but doesn't mention any of the username variables at all. (please ignore comments, I tend to write code and then forget why I've written it, helps when I need to explain things later on)